# How to retrieve full node from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to collect data from my firebase in order to view them inside a recyclerview yet i get an error in the

```
Machines machine = dataSnapshot.getValue(Machines.class)
```

the error is
`at com.example.machinerecycle.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:39)`

I have tried local data and it worked fine the recyclerview was perfect and so the data but when I change it to be read from firebase either I get that error or I get an empty list.

Here is myAdapter.java

```
package com.example.machinerecycle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.crypto.Mac;

public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Machines>machines;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<Machines> machines) {
        this.machines = machines;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_machines,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.id.setText(machines.get(position).getId());
        holder.cap1.setText(machines.get(position).getCap1());
        holder.cap2.setText(machines.get(position).getCap2());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return machines.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView id,cap1,cap2;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idMachine);
            cap1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cap1);
            cap2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cap2);

        }
    }
}
```

and this my mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.machinerecycle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ArrayList<Machines> machines;
    myAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvMachines);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("machines");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.exists()){
                   machines = new ArrayList<Machines>();
                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                   {
                       Machines machine = dataSnapshot.getValue(Machines.class);
                       machines.add(machine);
                   }
                   myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(machines);
                   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
               }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

this is how my firebase looks like

```
{
  "machines": {
    "machine1": {
      "ID": "M200",
      "cap1": 1,
      "cap2": 1
    },
    "machine10": {
      "ID": "M210",
      "cap1": 1,
      "cap2": 1
    },
    "machine2": {
      "ID": "M202",
      "cap1": 1,
      "cap2": 1
    },
    "machine3": {
      "ID": "M203",
      "cap1": 1,
      "cap2": 1
    },
    "machine4": {
      "ID": "M204",
      "cap1": 1,
      "cap2": 1,
    }
   }
}
```

Machines.java class :

```
package com.example.machinerecycle;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

public class Machines {
    private String id;
    private Integer cap1,cap2,state;

    public Machines(String id, Integer cap1, Integer cap2, Integer state) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cap1 = cap1;
        this.cap2 = cap2;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getCap1() {
        return cap1;
    }

    public void setCap1(Integer cap1) {
        this.cap1 = cap1;
    }

    public Integer getCap2() {
        return cap2;
    }

    public void setCap2(Integer cap2) {
        this.cap2 = cap2;
    }

    public Integer getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(Integer state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Can you also show us the content of `Machines` class?

Comment: "I get that error" What error? Please edit your question to include the exact error message, and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the blog and added the error, I apologies for my mistake.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have included the `Machines.java` class

Comment: Ok, and what's the error?

Comment: I also added it but here it is `at com.example.machinerecycle.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:39)`

Comment: Problem solved, all I need to do is build an empty constructer